# How to create a layout that all its cells are initially empty and accessible by moving agents (such as equipment)?

Tags: anylogic

In Copper Nickel Mine (Cloud) Simulation, In MinePanel Agent, there is a function Called setupTunnelLayout.

The original code in the above function is as following:

//create corridor of already empty rooms

```
     `RoomBlock emptyRoom;
for ( int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++ ) {
    
    emptyRoom = add_roomBlocks();
    emptyRoom.jumpToCell( 0, j );   
    if ( j == nColumns - 1 )
        emptyRoom.isStartBlock = true;
    emptyRoom.isTunnel = true;
}`
```

But in my scenario all the cells are accessible initially, so all can be tunnel (path to move), not only the (0, j) row as the above example!

I was thinking I can change it as the followings; (1) or (2);
(1)
//create corridor of already empty rooms

```
     RoomBlock emptyRoom;
for ( int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++ ) 
     for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    
    emptyRoom = add_roomBlocks();
    emptyRoom.jumpToCell( 0, j );
    emptyRoom.jumpToCell( i, 0 );   
    if ( j == nColumns - 1 )
        emptyRoom.isStartBlock = true;
    emptyRoom.isTunnel = true;
}
```

Or it can be like this;
(2)
//create corridor of already empty rooms

```
    `RoomBlock emptyRoom;
for ( int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++ ) 
     for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    
    emptyRoom = add_roomBlocks();
    emptyRoom.jumpToCell( i, j );   
    if ( j == nColumns - 1 )
        emptyRoom.isStartBlock = true;
    emptyRoom.isTunnel = true;
}`
```

'Can you please let me know if (1) or (2) are correct? Which one is preferred?

Thank you so much,
Neda.'

Comment: try them both and test which one is correct, I would recommend :)

Comment: :) All right! Thank you @Benjamin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is preferable; there is no point jumping the agent to the column and *then* the row when you can directly move it to the exact cell coordinates.

In both cases though you are missing a closing `}` for your extra `i` loop (and you're missing an opening one in your second case).

```java
//create corridor of already empty rooms
RoomBlock emptyRoom;
for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) { 
      emptyRoom = add_roomBlocks();
      emptyRoom.jumpToCell(i, j);   
      if (j == nColumns - 1) {
        emptyRoom.isStartBlock = true;
      }
      emptyRoom.isTunnel = true;
   }
}
```

[I used the StackOverflow [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to mark the full block as Java code. It's also best-practice (although AnyLogic doesn't do it many of their example models) to always use curly brackets for loops, etc. even if their body only has one line.]

Plus whether the change will do what you want or not obviously depends on the rest of the model and how it handles the grid of cells and tunnels.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply @Stuart Rossiter.  Very useful indeed.